# MYSQL Order of Operations failing: ORDER BY is affecting the results of SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to solve this question on HackerRank using MySQL.
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/occupations

> Pivot the Occupation column in OCCUPATIONS so that each Name is sorted alphabetically and displayed underneath its corresponding Occupation. The output column headers should Doctor, Professor, Singer, and Actor, respectively.

```
#Input Format

Samantha Doctor
Jenny Doctor
Ashley Professor
...

#Sample Output

Jenny    Ashley     Meera  Jane
Samantha Christeen  Priya  Julia
NULL     Ketty      NULL   Maria
```

And this is the solution given for MYSQL:

```
set @r1=0, @r2=0, @r3=0, @r4=0;
select min(Doctor), min(Professor), min(Singer), min(Actor) from(
    select case when Occupation='Doctor' then (@r1:=@r1+1)
        when Occupation='Professor' then (@r2:=@r2+1)
        when Occupation='Singer' then (@r3:=@r3+1)
        when Occupation='Actor' then (@r4:=@r4+1) end as RowNumber,
    case when Occupation='Doctor' then Name end as Doctor,
    case when Occupation='Professor' then Name end as Professor,
    case when Occupation='Singer' then Name end as Singer,
    case when Occupation='Actor' then Name end as Actor
from OCCUPATIONS
order by Name
) Temp
group by RowNumber
```

This returns the output in alphabetical order as opposed to a random order because the RowNumber has changed due to the ORDER BY statement.

My question is is why does *order By Name* affect the ordering of the column RowNumber?

*The Order of Operations in SQL says that all SELECT Statements happen before the ORDER BY Statements. Shouldn't the row number already be calculated when the ORDER BY happens?*

**edit**:
Since people are asking about Order of Operations, I've included links of the multiple places where I've seen it (not to mention my SQL textbook): 
http://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm

Comment: That is why whenever I do stuff like this I put the order by in a subquery that is used by such incrementing calculations. Technically the SELECT should happen before the ORDER BY, but that doesn't mean MySQL won't use "hints" earlier; similarly to how MySQL won't ignore a helpful WHERE condition in favor of generating joining entire tables before using the conditions to reduce result rows.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What do you mean by SQL "hints" from EARLIER? I thought the SELECT statement should have already executed by the time it even got to the ORDER BY. This would've caused the row number variables to already be set/printed by the time it arrived at the ORDER BY statement

Comment: `ORDER BY` can take advantage of indexes; indexes do not really pertain to the results of a select, so it has to be capable of using such an index before the select is completely evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

First, *where* does it say that in the order of operations that a `SELECT` is *executed* before the `ORDER BY`?  That statement is simply not true.

What *is* true is that the `SELECT` is *evaluated by the compiler* before the `ORDER BY`.  For this reason, column aliases defined in the `SELECT` are available to the `ORDER BY`.

Beyond that, variables are an extension to SQL.  [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) is quite explicit that `SELECT` is the last clause that is executed:

> In a `SELECT` statement, each select expression is evaluated only when
>   sent to the client. This means that in a HAVING, GROUP BY, or ORDER BY
>   clause, referring to a variable that is assigned a value in the select
>   expression list does not work as expected . . .

Because `ORDER BY` occurs before results are returned to the client, the data is ordered before the evaluation of the expressions with variables.

Comment: Oddly enough, MySQL's example `SELECT (@aa:=id) AS a, (@aa+3) AS b FROM tbl_name HAVING b=5;` seems to only break the results because of the groupless `HAVING`. If you add a `GROUP BY` and/or `ORDER BY`, the results come out how you would expect with left-to-right field evaluation.

Comment: @Uueerdo . . . I would expect the results to be indeterminate ;)

Comment: ...further experiments with similar queries seem to indicate it evaluates such fields' calculations twice (first for having and then for select) when only a having is present. With a `SELECT (@aa:=id) AS a,  (@aa+id) AS b FROM tbl_name HAVING b = 4;` I received different results on successive iterations. _Indicating `b` was evaluated for the `HAVING` independently of `a`._

Comment: @Uueerdo . . . If your point is that one should ignore the documentation in favor of a handful of tests on limited data on a single version of the code running on a single machine, then I don't think that is good advice.  I strongly advise users of a database to heed the documentation on how to use the database  effectively.

Comment: My point is just the the order of evaluation is not as clear as the OP expected, but has some historically predictable behaviors. (It's not just _"a handful of tests on limited data on a single version of the code running on a single machine"_, I've been able to use session variables like this reliably across numerous server versions, on at least dozens of servers, over more than 10 years... but I refrain from using them across clauses, very rarely have a `HAVING` without a `GROUP BY` in general, and almost always force the order in a subquery beforehand if it is important.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added a reference to my original post for the order of operations that other people are stated for SQL. I guess those Order of operations do not apply to MySQL and are only for other variants?

Comment: @BrianLin . . . What you call "the order of operations" is really the "order of compilation".  The ultimate operations run by the database engine are dataflow operations that might not have a one-to-one correspondence to clauses in the original query.

Answer (score 1):

The order of evaluation is *undefined*.

From the MySQL Reference Manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html:

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:
>
> `SET @a = @a + 1;`
>
> For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second:
>
> `SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;`
>
> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables **is undefined.**

---

As @Uueerdo commented, we can usually get around this with an inline view (derived table).  Do the ORDER BY inside the inline view, then SELECT from that and do the operations with the user-defined variables.

Also, I don't believe there is any guarantee that the expressions in the CASE expression won't be executed... the CASE expression only has to return the value of the expression, it doesn't guarantee that the assignment won't happen.

---

With something like this, the behavior is still undefined, but we usually observe more consistent behavior:

```
 SELECT MIN(IF(s.Occupation='Doctor'    ,s.Name,NULL)) AS Doctor
      , MIN(IF(s.Occupation='Professor' ,s.Name,NULL)) AS Professor
      , MIN(IF(s.Occupation='Singer'    ,s.Name,NULL)) AS Singer
      , MIN(IF(s.Occupation='Actor'     ,s.Name,NULL)) AS Actor
   FROM ( SELECT t.Name
               , t.Occupation
               , @r1 := @r1 + IF(t.Occupation='Doctor'    ,1,0) AS r1
               , @r2 := @r2 + IF(t.Occupation='Professor' ,1,0) AS r2
               , @r3 := @r3 + IF(t.Occupation='Singer'    ,1,0) AS r3
               , @r3 := @r4 + IF(t.Occupation='Actor'     ,1,0) AS r4
            FROM OCCUPATIONS t
           CROSS
            JOIN ( SELECT @r1:=0, @r2:=0, @r3:=0, @r4:=0 ) i
           WHERE t.Occupation IN ('Doctor','Professor','Singer','Actor')
           ORDER BY t.Name, t.Occupation
        ) s
  GROUP BY CASE s.Occupation
           WHEN 'Doctor'    THEN s.r1
           WHEN 'Professor' THEN s.r2
           WHEN 'Singer'    THEN s.r3
           WHEN 'Actor'     THEN s.r4
           ELSE NULL
           END
  ORDER BY CASE s.Occupation
           WHEN 'Doctor'    THEN s.r1
           WHEN 'Professor' THEN s.r2
           WHEN 'Singer'    THEN s.r3
           WHEN 'Actor'     THEN s.r4
           ELSE NULL
           END
```

(not tested.)

This may still have problems because of the order of operations. to address that, we can use an inline view to get MySQL to perform the sort operation before we do the row numbering...

```
 SELECT MIN(IF(s.Occupation='Doctor'    ,s.Name,NULL)) AS Doctor
      , MIN(IF(s.Occupation='Professor' ,s.Name,NULL)) AS Professor
      , MIN(IF(s.Occupation='Singer'    ,s.Name,NULL)) AS Singer
      , MIN(IF(s.Occupation='Actor'     ,s.Name,NULL)) AS Actor
   FROM ( SELECT t.Name
               , t.Occupation
               , @r1 := @r1 + IF(t.Occupation='Doctor'    ,1,0) AS r1
               , @r2 := @r2 + IF(t.Occupation='Professor' ,1,0) AS r2
               , @r3 := @r3 + IF(t.Occupation='Singer'    ,1,0) AS r3
               , @r3 := @r4 + IF(t.Occupation='Actor'     ,1,0) AS r4
            FROM ( SELECT u.Name
                        , u.Occupation
                     FROM OCCUPATIONS u
                    WHERE u.Occupation IN ('Doctor','Professor','Singer','Actor')
                    ORDER BY u.Name
                 ) t
           CROSS
            JOIN ( SELECT @r1:=0, @r2:=0, @r3:=0, @r4:=0 ) i
        ) s
  GROUP BY CASE s.Occupation
           WHEN 'Doctor'    THEN s.r1
           WHEN 'Professor' THEN s.r2
           WHEN 'Singer'    THEN s.r3
           WHEN 'Actor'     THEN s.r4
           ELSE NULL
           END
  ORDER BY CASE s.Occupation
           WHEN 'Doctor'    THEN s.r1
           WHEN 'Professor' THEN s.r2
           WHEN 'Singer'    THEN s.r3
           WHEN 'Actor'     THEN s.r4
           ELSE NULL
           END
```

Comment: In my experience, the fields in a SELECT are evaluated left to right; it seems like people get into trouble with session variables when they start pulling from and assigning to the variables in the same field expression, something like `IF(@i <> 1, @i := 1, @i)` tends to cause issues _(not specifically that, that might be fine, just giving general "format" of uses that cause problems)_.

Comment: I've run into problems doing an assignment inside an IF function. I do my increment assignment outside of functions, expressions... e.g.   SELECT `@v := @v + expr_return_1_or_0`.  I know that the evaluation of the expression has to be done before the addition, and before the assignment.

Comment: Yeah, I usually err on the side of paranoia like that when I need to use and update a session variable in the same select expression. The one equivalent I would actually use, compared to what was in my previous comment, would be `@i := IF(@i > 1, 1, @i)`

Comment: @Uueerdo: yes, like that. According to the docs, it's not guaranteed that @i inside the IF expression will be evaluated before the assignment. But I can't see any reasonable way that the engine wouldn't..  the right side of the assignment has to be evaluated before it's assigned to the left side. And where I get really paranoid is using a SELECT that manipulates user-defined variables in this way, inside a DML (insert/update/delete) statement.